# Mysql count query by Grouping Year and Month horizontal

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql query and i am stuck on getting query. Basically, i want the date to group as Year and month (Jan'17, Feb'17...) in horizontal way (column) as shown in Image below.
[image: Count]

Data are shown in image below:

[image: Data image]

Please help to create query.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation - once per login_id and then overall and then union both the results.

```
Select login_idindex,
  Sum(date_format(visitdate, '%Y%m')  = '201701' ) as jan_17,
  Sum(date_format(visitdate, '%Y%m')  = '201702' ) as feb_17,
  . . .,
  Count(*) as total
From your_table
Where visitdate between ? and ?
Group by login_idindex

Union all

Select null,
  Sum(date_format(visitdate, '%Y%m')  = '201701' ) as jan_17,
  Sum(date_format(visitdate, '%Y%m')  = '201702' ) as feb_17,
  . . .,
  Count(*) as total
From your_table
Where visitdate between ? and ?;
```

Replace `?` with actual dates or remove the where clause if you are working with all the dates.